# Remove vowels from string C++

Tags: c++, regex, string, str-replace

So I am new to C++ and tried to create a function that would remove vowels from a string, but I am failing at it horribly, Here is my code so far :

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string remove(string st) {
    for(int i = 0; st[i] != '\0'; i++) 
        st[i] = st[i] == 'a' || st[i] == 'e' || st[i] == 'i' || st[i] == 'o' || st[i] ==
        'u' || st[i] == 'A' || st[i] == 'E' || st[i] == 'I' || st[i] == 'O' || st[i] ==
        'U' ? '' : st[i];
    }
return st;
```

This seems to throw an error ? any idea what I am doing wrong

The error I get is :

```
main.cpp:10:16: error: expected expression 'U' ? '' : Z[i];
```

And running on another interpreter :

```
   .code.tio.cpp:7:14: error: incompatible operand types ('const char *' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' (aka 'char'))
            'U' ? "" : Z[i];
                ^ ~~   ~~~~
```

Comment: What error does it "throw"?

Comment: `''` is not a valid character value. Maybe you want to use a space character or something instead, but it won't "remove" that character from the string, just replace it's value.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Thanks, should have been `!=`

Comment: Seems like [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) might be a better tool for this job.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace "seems to throw an error" with an accurate description of what you're observing.

Comment: @DrewDormann : done, should have done that the first time

Comment: please make sure the error is from the code you show, the error says `""` but code says `''`

Comment: @user463035818 I interpreted that as `''` with extra quotes introduced by the error message's format, indicating the unexpected token.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman -- As pointed out, `std::remove_if` (and `std::erase`) makes this a one or two line function.  Is your goal to get the final results correct, or to keep the code you have now and attempt to fix it?

Comment: It's a shame the c++ community is so quick to downvote-and-forget. The question's problems were fixed quickly after being pointed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical way to remove elements from a sequential containers according to a predicate (a condition) is to use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Unlike it's name implies, this standard algorithm doesn't quite remove the elements, it moves them to the back of the container so they are easy to erase, leaving the other elements intact and in the same order. It returns an iterator that indicates the beginning of the portion of the container which contains the "removed" elements. Since the standard algorithms cannot change the size the containers they operate on, these elements must then be removed using the container's appropriate remove method. In the case of `std::string`, that's [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

`std::remove_if` accepts a pair of iterators which define the range of elements to inspect, as well as a predicate that is used to determine which elements to remove. Elements for which the predicate is `true` are removed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Returns true if p_char is a vowel
bool is_vowel(const char p_char)
{

    constexpr char vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    return std::find(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), p_char) != std::end(vowels);
}

std::string remove_vowel(std::string st) 
{
    // Moves all the characters for which `is_vowel` is true to the back
    //  and returns an iterator to the first such character
    auto to_erase = std::remove_if(st.begin(), st.end(), is_vowel);

    // Actually remove the unwanted characters from the string
    st.erase(to_erase, st.end());
    return st;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << remove_vowel("Hello, World!");
}
```

Comment: Holy. Nice. I'm impressed.

Comment: The mandatory STL-heavy response in any StackOverflow C++ post :)

Comment: Note that I've renamed the function to `remove_vowel` as `remove` was conflicting with [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove), though I don't know how it gets included.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman -- Also, note that the function is named exactly as described.  In other words, any STL knowledgeable person can take one look at the code and know what it does and that it works, all without having to debug or step through the code.  On the other hand, hand-coded loops have to be 1) figured out what is being done and 2) is it doing it correctly.

Comment: I rather like this code ... and I find the description of remove_if (in cppreference.com) unreadable.  Your description here is great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`''` is not a valid character, you cannot place an "empty" one (such thing does not exist in C++) into the string to remove content...

What you can do is moving the non-vowels, i. e. the consonants, to front, skipping the vowels, and afterwards erase the surplus characters at the end:

```
auto pos = st.begin();
for(auto c : st)
{
    if(isConsonant(c))
        *pos++ = c;
}
st.erase(pos, st.end());
```

Edit: As François (correctly) denotes: There is no need to re-invent the wheel (provided you are not disallowed to use the standard library):

```
st.erase(std::remove_if(st.begin(), st.end(), [](char c) { return isConsonant(c); }), st.end());
```

Be aware that `std::remove_if` (as well as `std::remove`) "remove" by just moving the elements to remain to front and returns an iterator to the new end of data – but does not really remove the elements "behind" the new end. So it is necessary to explicitly `erase` them as shown above.

Comment: Ahh, I see. so I cannot just put an empty string. My bad used to JS , python. Thanks I will see what this is

Comment: I am assuming that `isConstant` function is not part of C++ ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Can you write an answer with `std::remove_if` ? My C++ is really bad ? otherwise a link that explains that ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Right, otherwise it would reside in namespace `std` (and likely be all small letters). Just used a custom function name to shorten the code, use the test you had in your original question instead...

Comment: @MuhammadSalman: See the example code [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @Aconcagua : Thanks

Comment: @FredLarson : Thanks