# Is there any way to add char in string?

Tags: c++, string, char

have string `"cdfrcs"`. I want to get string `*c*d*f*r*c*s`(add stars before every symbol). How should I do it?

Comment: received string must be *c*d*f*r*c*s.   problem link: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A

Comment: `std::string` or `char*` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex_replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) to add an asterisk before every character in an `input` string:

```
auto result = std::regex_replace(input, std::regex{"(.)"}, "*$1");
```

In the regex `(.)`, the `.` matches every character, and `()` captures it in capture group 1.

The replacement string `*$1` specifies that every captured character `$1` is replaced with a preceding `*`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TTnExY9ch).

Comment: bro I used this way but the result is not desired. Why?                             
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string s;
 cin >> s;
 auto result = regex_replace(s, regex{ "(.)" }, "*$1");
 cout << result;
}

Comment: @YoungCoder I don't know. Does `s` have spaces in it? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: *c*o*d*e*f*o*r*c*e*s is result.  it does not move letters. adds only stars before every letter

Comment: @YoungCoder We're not going to go off-site to test the program. You need to [edit] the question to explain clearly what the result should be. At the moment, it says "add stars before every symbol", and doesn't mention anything about "moving".

Comment: oh my mistake sorry for being confusing. From word "codeforces" I have to remove vowels and the rest of the letters must be in order but with stars in front of them. For instance, from "codeforces" we got "cdfrcs" and output must be with stars "cdfrcs" with stars in front of the letters. Thank you bro for your attention and time. Hope everything is clear now

Comment: @YoungCoder Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845519). You can combine the solution there along with the one in my answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, the following works:

```
std::string a = "cdfrcs";
std::string b = "";
for(char c : a) {
    b += std::string("*") + c;
}
```